# Magento : multiple websites and multiple controllers override

Tags: magento, controller, overriding, checkout

I'm facing a problem that I'm not sure there's a solution. 
Actually, we have a magento website A and a magento website B, both of them using the same core sources. Because both of them have some specification, we overrided some parts of the code in the website corresponding folder.

So actually, both websites are using the Checkout module of the website A. But the checkout behavior of the B website have to change now and I'm looking for a way to rewrite the controller for the B website only.

So my question is : how can I rewrite the checkout controller in the A folder only for the A website and rewrite the same controller in the B folder, only for the B website ?

I already tried to do something like the following without any success :

A site -> config.xml

```
<routers>
    <checkout>
        <args>
            <modules>
                <Mage_Checkout>Mage_Checkout</Mage_Checkout>
                <A_Checkout before="Mage_Checkout">A_Checkout</A_Checkout>
                <frontname>checkout</frontname>
            </modules>
        </args>
    </checkout>
</routers>
```

B site -> config.xml

```
<routers>
    <checkout>
        <args>
            <modules>
                <Mage_Checkout>Mage_Checkout</Mage_Checkout>
                <B_Checkout before="A_Checkout">B_Checkout</B_Checkout>
                <frontname>checkout</frontname>
            </modules>
        </args>
    </checkout>
</routers>
```

Problem is that the B checkout controller is called first.

In this situation, my only solution looks like to check the websiteId and then call the parent function if we're on the A site or continue if we're on the B website.

Could you tell me if this looks like a good solution ? Or am I missing something ?

Thank you very much for any advices !

Seb

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to create two similar templates and assign one template to store A and another to store B.
Now for store B template apply whatever modification you want one page checkout.

here you will still be sharing same core code but just at block and template level you will need to modify which is much easier then customizing.